# How to disable the "Global error handler detected" warning in vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm creating async tests using `vue-test-utils` and `jest` using the approach described here:

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#what-about-nexttick

where you set `Vue.config.errorHandler = done` like shown below

```
  test('Then we are shown events in EventCreate component', done => {
    Vue.config.errorHandler = done
```

This is working and when an error is thrown in a promise handler in a component my tests will fail. However I'm getting this warning.

```
    console.error node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:1421
      [vue-test-utils]: Global error handler detected (Vue.config.errorHandler). 
      Vue Test Utils sets a custom error handler to throw errors thrown by instances. If you want this behavior in your tests, you must remove the global error handler.
```

I don't want to spam my test output with this warning. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
  console.error.mockImplementation(() => 'some error');
        });
afterEach(() => {
  console.error.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: How would that work for disabling one specific warning like above? Are you recommending I parse the warnings and ignore the ones that I care about.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, I had a similar case where it was throwing errors while running unit tests which I didn't want, so I mocked the console.error

Comment: Well, it looks to me like that could swallow all errors, I just want this one warning disabled.

Comment: can you show if possible small gist of your code, what you are trying to test