# VueJs how to remove global error handler for testing with vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs, vue-test-utils

I am running a unit test for a canvas in vue (test is passing). However i get the error  `console.error node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:1735 [vue-test-utils]: Global error handler detected (Vue.config.errorHandler).  Vue Test Utils sets a custom error handler to throw errors thrown by instances. If you want this behavior in your tests, you must remove the global error handler.`

I tried deactivating the error handler , but this seems not to be supported? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler How can I apply the suggestion from the error message?

There is a similar question here: [How to disable the "Global error handler detected" warning in vue test utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086098/how-to-disable-the-global-error-handler-detected-warning-in-vue-test-utils), but no useful answer.

My test is written using jest and fabric (for the canvas):

```
import FabricCanvas from './FabricCanvas';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { shallowMount  } from '@vue/test-utils';

import PolygonDrawing from "@/components/labeling/editor/drawing/PolygonDrawing";

function getFabricCanvas(): fabric.Canvas {
  const wrapper = shallowMount (FabricCanvas);
  const canvas = wrapper.get('#main-canvas').html();
  return new fabric.Canvas(canvas, {
      width: 1024,
      height: 1024,
  } as any);
}

let fCanvas: fabric.Canvas | undefined;

beforeAll(() => {
  fCanvas = getFabricCanvas();
})

  test('add a Polygon to the canvas startDrawingPolygon and stopDrawingPolygon', () => {
    const polygonDrawing = new PolygonDrawing();
    if (fCanvas) {
      expect(fCanvas._objects.length).toStrictEqual(0);
    }
    const objectClass = 'Vehicle';
    const shapeType = 'polygon';
    let startMousePoint = {x: 200, y: 200};
    polygonDrawing.startDrawingPolygon(fCanvas, startMousePoint, objectClass, shapeType);
    startMousePoint = {x: 300, y: 300};
    polygonDrawing.startDrawingPolygon(fCanvas, startMousePoint, objectClass, shapeType);
    startMousePoint = {x: 200, y: 300};
    polygonDrawing.startDrawingPolygon(fCanvas, startMousePoint, objectClass, shapeType);
    
    if (fCanvas) {
      polygonDrawing.stopDrawingPolygon(fCanvas, shapeType, objectClass);
      expect(fCanvas._objects.length).toStrictEqual(1);
    }
  })
});
```

The canvas is mocked using the file FabricCanvas.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="canvas-container">
        <canvas width="1024" height="1024" id="main-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class FabricCanvas extends Vue {
    }
</script>

<style scoped> </style>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `Vue.config.errorHandler`? And where do you try to deactivate it?

Comment: I am not setting `Vue.config.errorHandler` anywhere explicitly, it is just part of `vue-test-utils.js`.  I tried unsuccessfully deactivating it in the test file (the one above) by  using ```import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
  console.log('hi there');
  
  // handle error
  // `info` is a Vue-specific error info, e.g. which lifecycle hook
  // the error was found in. Only available in 2.2.0+
}```

Comment: I can only reproduce the warning if I explicitly set it in my main code, and then run tests, so I'm assuming your code must be setting it somehow. Also, your deactivation code is not really doing what you intend because it simply sets a new error handler (even though it's a no-op). To deactivate it, set it to null.

Comment: Hey, ok hm, i don't really know where that could be... How could I find out? Searching for `errorHandler` does not yield any results except the mentioned `vue-test-utils.js`. Also, how would I set it to null? `Vue.config.errorHandler = null;` gives me a Typescript error :`Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(err: Error, vm: Vue, info: string) => void'.` Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints by [@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19) I found the solution: There was a plugin from Elastic called APM (Application Performace Monitoring) that was inside my router/index.js: `import { ApmVuePlugin } from '@elastic/apm-rum-vue';`

This was reponsible for the duplicate Global error handler, deactivating it during tests solved the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my Project I use `vue2` with `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` and `vitest`. I had the similar error. I fixed it by removing the 'threads'-option in my `vitest.config.js`

```json
// vitest.config.js
{
  ...
  threads: true,
  ...
}
```